# Laravel connection error in macOS Mojave?

Tags: mysql, laravel

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * where
>   `uid=501(isa) gid=20(staff)
>   groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),701(com`.`apple`.`sharepoint`.`group`.`1),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com`.`apple`.`access_ftp),398(com`.`apple`.`access_screensharing),399(com`.`apple`.`access_ssh)`
>    = 1 limit 1)

[image: error page]

Comment: Would you please have a look before asking a question in StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you mention how are you trying to connect to MySQL database?

Comment: through Xampp @tha07

Comment: can you show us the laravel .env configuration for database connection

Comment: if you suggest to change local host to 127. ... I did it, also, I try to create another user and then replace it with the deafult ones, the error still remains

Comment: Did your database get trashed during the upgrade? "No such file" usually means the database doesn't exist. Try a very simple query, like `SELECT * FROM ...` where that's the table name. This query looks really bizarre.

Comment: I actually can't make sense of what this query is supposed to be. That `WHERE` condition looks like a programming error where you're specifying some kind of associative array to what should be something else.